# Unable to calculate the size of a json response

Tags: karate

I was trying to calculate size of a json response and store it in a variable.

`$..security[*] == '#[_>1]'`

works fine but I wanted this number to be dynamic and to be calculated at the runtime. When I try

```
size($..security[*]) or Karate.SizeOf($..security[*])
```

it doesn't give me the count. Is there any other way to get the size of the Json response. I found these methods in the Karate documentation. Can someone please help me with this.

I tried

```
 size($..security[*]) or Karate.SizeOf($..security[*])
```

but didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Since 0.9.4 [`karate.sizeOf()`](https://github.com/intuit/karate#karate-sizeof) works:

```
* def foo = { a: 1 }
* def size = karate.sizeOf(foo)
* print size
```